# Cookie always return null in IE

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm debugging a script, that basically reads a cookie and returns some stuff. It works fine in all browsers, except for IE. After some testing, I discover that it never enters the `for` loop.

```
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);

    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {   
        return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }

  }
  return null;
}
```

After some more testing, I realize the variable `ca`, which store the cookie, never even gets defined. Looking at it, I don't see why it should, as there is no reference to the cookiename. So in my logic, it shouldn't even work, yet it works perfectly in everything **but** IE.

```
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
```

**1: Why does this even work in Fx, Webkit and Opera?

2: How can I make it work in IE as well?**

I tried defining it as below, but that didn't seem to work:

```
document.cookie = name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there are no cookies set in IE. Try using

```
alert('d.cookie:\t'+document.cookie+'\n\n'+'d.cookie.length:\t'+document.cookie.length);
```

to check if there are any cookies.

↪ [Bookmarklet](http://pastehtml.com/raw/c1ckidb3a.html)

If there are none, try setting one using

```
document.cookie='mycookie=foo; path=/';
```

↪ [Bookmarklet](http://pastehtml.com/raw/c1cl43mo6.html)

Comment: The cookie is set like that in a different script.

Comment: Are you sure that cookies are enabled in IE?

Comment: Oh, for crying out loud. That's seems the exact issue! For some reason, both my machines have cookies disabled (and I can only assume it's disabled on the clients machines as well). Embarrassing!